# Java-Springboot service running in EKS Fargate throws java.net.SocketException: Connection reset on the first call

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-eks, aws-fargate

We recently migrated a service running in EC2 instances to EKS Fargate. During testing we found some intermittent connection reset exception when trying to connect the the service using a load balancer(NLB).

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://go.xxxxxxxxxxx.com/api/push": Connection reset; nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:785) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:711) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:437) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
    at com.venuetize.airship.services.RestService.postObject(RestService.java:49) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.venuetize.airship.services.AirshipIntegrationService.sendNotification(AirshipIntegrationService.java:312) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.venuetize.airship.controllers.NotificationController.sendNotification(NotificationController.java:47) [classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) [spring-web-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) [spring-web-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) [spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) [spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) [spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) [spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) [spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) [spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) [spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) [spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:?]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) [spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.53.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:?]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) [spring-web-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:?]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:?]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) [spring-web-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:769) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1726) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) [?:?]
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:186) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:484) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.readHeader(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:478) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.bytesInCompletePacket(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:70) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readApplicationRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1455) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:1066) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:137) ~[httpcore-4.4.14.jar!/:4.4.14]
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:153) ~[httpcore-4.4.14.jar!/:4.4.14]
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:280) ~[httpcore-4.4.14.jar!/:4.4.14]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:138) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259) ~[httpcore-4.4.14.jar!/:4.4.14]
    at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:163) ~[httpcore-4.4.14.jar!/:4.4.14]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:157) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273) ~[httpcore-4.4.14.jar!/:4.4.14]
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125) ~[httpcore-4.4.14.jar!/:4.4.14]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:272) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
    at org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.java:87) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:66) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.http.client.BufferingClientHttpRequestWrapper.executeInternal(BufferingClientHttpRequestWrapper.java:63) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:66) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
    at com.venuetize.airship.utils.VzRequestResponseLoggingInterceptor.intercept(VzRequestResponseLoggingInterceptor.java:24) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
    at com.venuetize.xtrace.interceptor.XTraceIdForwardingInterceptor.intercept(XTraceIdForwardingInterceptor.java:77) ~[xtrace-0.5.1.jar!/:?]
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:77) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:66) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:776) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
    ... 57 more
```

The only observable pattern with multiple days of testing is, if I wait few hours or days between testing I'll see this exception but then the subsequent calls work fine. So it seems to be some networking issue and would like some guidance into this.